# The difference between 和谐，和睦 and 融洽？

Tags: meaning, difference

Anyone can tell me the difference between 和谐，和睦 and 融洽？

Answer (score 3):

> **和谐**(adj): harmonious; balanced (**between elements**) | *e.g. 氣氛和谐 (harmonious atmosphere); 和谐景象 (harmonious scene)*
>
> 和谐(n): harmony | *e.g. 達致和谐 (achieve harmony)*
>
> 和谐(adv): harmoniously/ in harmony | *e.g. 和谐共處 (harmoniously stay/live together; harmoniously co-exist)*

~

> **和睦**(adj): friendly; harmonious (**between people**) | *e.g. 關係和睦 (friendly relationship)*
>
> 和睦(adv): harmoniously | *e.g. 和睦共處 (harmoniously stay/live together); 待人和睦 (treat people with friendliness)*

~

> **融洽** (adj) harmonious (**between people or element**)| *e.g. 關係融洽 (friendly relationship); 氣氛融洽 (harmonious atmosphere)*
>
> 融洽 (adv): on friendly terms; on good relationship with | *e.g. 相處融洽 (harmoniously interact/ live together)*

Main difference is when they are in adjective role, 和谐 apply to elements, 和睦 apply to people and 融洽 apply to either people or elements

The difference between 和睦 and 融洽 is in the construction of the term. [和(peaceful/ in harmony) + 睦(befriend) = 和睦 (friendly/ harmonious) ]; [融(melt) + 洽 (arrange) = 融洽 (harmonious)

Answer (score 0):

融洽 means action or felling or thought are synchronized. Like when two people are in sync, and one know what the other think by simply observing his movement and will act accordingly. Or something like that.

和睦 means harmonious relationships with other people like husband \wife. Example,

> ③唐 陈子昂《座右铭》：“兄弟敦和睦，朋友笃信诚。” means harmonious brotherhood and faithful friendships.

和谐 as a verb could be used to mean because of broken of a rule, being dealt with. for example, "你今天在论坛上发言被和谐了吧" meaning you said something not appropriate and hence being dealt with by the authorities.

it also mean reconcile like when a king send his daughter to a political marriage to ease the tension between kingdoms. I hope this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

how did this question arise? It would seem any differences are fully explained in online dictionaries, esp. bkrs, iciba, etc., specialized dictionaries on synonyms like ＂汉语同义词词典＂do not list any two of them together,＂汉语同义词词典＂ only has 和谐／调谐 (bkrs：frequency ranks: #4381,#33928) **［同］** 形容词。形容配合得适当。用于书面语。**［异］** **［和谐］** 着重于不矛盾，彼此融合。可用于音调、颜色、线条、建筑物或摆设的布局以及人的生活、行为举止等。常形容＂旋律、声音、节奏、情调、色调、关系、气氛＂等。 **例**：（１）塘中的月色并不均匀但光与影有着和谐的旋律，如梵婀玲（[英violin]西洋乐器。小提琴）上奏着的名曲。（朱自清＜荷塘月色＞）（２）已经近午了，村鸡在啼，狗睡在麦田里，野外的羊群，时常发出羊的和谐叫声，（周立波＜娘子关前＞）（３）因为我们过着一种和谐的生活。（何其芳＜树阴下的默想＞）（４）那一年酷热的夏天，园子里渐渐失去了和谐宁静。（何为＜园林城中一个小庭园＞）**［调谐］** 着重于配合得恰到好处。对象多是音调、色彩、建筑物或摆设的布局等，不能用于人的生活、行为举止。使用频率比＂和谐＂低。文学语体。**例**（１）而音波的调谐振荡却仍然留在这个苦病迷茫的童子的枕边，仍然沉坠于他的小心。（王统照＜＜小天分人＞的生与死＞）（２）再没有比这一群建筑更调谐更匀称的了！（叙志摩＜我所知道的康桥＞）
**［附］**＂调谐＂兼属名词。指调节可变电容器（variable condenser）或线图使收音机与无线电波达到谐振（resonance)，如＂扩音机的面板上有许多旋钮，其顺序（从左到右）是：话管音量(pitch)、拾音音量(pickup)、高低音控制、收音音量、调谐、波段选择、高压开关和低压开关＂。

Answer (score 0):

和谐，harmony in general, especially in the sense of aesthetic.

和睦 harmony among family members.

融洽 harmony in terms of interpersonal relationship.

Answer (score 0):

和谐，比较general，有很多意思。比如阴阳达到平衡。社会不发生冲突。

和睦，一般来说用于邻里间或国与国之间（Live in harmony with your neighbours），尤其指长期以来的关系。加拿大与美国关系历来很和睦。

融洽，一般用来形容人与人之间的关系，尤其可能预期相处会不好，但结果很好。小明转学后和同学相处得很融洽。朝韩两国代表会议气氛很融洽。